# groovy interpretation of `this` when inheritance applied

Tags: java, inheritance, groovy, this

Given simple code

```
class Parent {
    private String name

    Parent(String name) {
        Parent o = this
        o.name = name
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    Child(String name) {
        super(name)
    }
}


@Test
void a() {
    new Child('a')
}
```

When compiled and run with groovy it fails with `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: name for class: com.example.Child`

When compiled and run as plain java it works.
Is it a bug in groovy or is it intended behavior?

Comment: What Groovy version is this?

Comment: I've just tried this in Groovy 2.5.6 and 3.0.6 and both have the bug. I assume it's a bug because if it works in Java (and I agree it should work) then it should work in Groovy too.

Comment: OTOH because Groovy uses dynamic dispatch (i.e. the runtime type of the object is used when dispatching, rather than Java that uses static dispatching) this will try to call `setName` on the `Child` class which doesn't expose it (as it's private in the parent class). So I am torn on whether it's a bug in Groovy or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of Groovy using [multiple dispatch](https://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_method_selection_algorithm) (or multi-methods) rather than Java's static dispatch.

This means that the method Groovy will call depends on the runtime type of the object, not its static type.

In your example, Groovy is trying to call `o.setName(a)` where `o` has type `Child` (even if you only declare it with `Parent` type... that's what it means to use the runtime type to dispatch methods!).

You can fix this by using `@CompileStatic`, which changes the semantics to be like Java's static dispatch (which can cause surprising behaviour sometimes, but it's much faster).

This example works fine:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Parent {
    private String name

    Parent(String name) {
        Parent o = this
        o.@name = name
    }
    
    String toString() { "Parent($name)" }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    Child(String name) {
        super(name)
    }

}

new Child('b')
```

Notice that I also had to change assignment to use the field-access syntax: `o.@name = name` because otherwise Groovy would try to call `o.setName(name)`, but because the field is private, that method would not have been generated by Groovy.